# How to optimize loop and data storage in SQLite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, optimization

### Issue

I am currently trying to create a database of comments and replies from Reddit. I am following [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/chatbot-deep-learning-python-tensorflow/) tutorial for the project.

I have reached the part where the file of reddit comments need to be read in and stored into a SQLite database.

It takes roughly 1m30s to process 100 000 rows, which I think could be improved. I have tried switching the project over to my SSD which didn't improve the speeds. I also tried increasing the file buffer but that didn't help either. I can't see another way of doing the file read and loop. Can someone possibly suggest a more efficient way?

### Code

```
with open('D:/Projects/Personal/AI/ChatBot/RC_{}'.format(timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
    for row in f:
        row_counter += 1

        if row_counter > start_row:
            try:
                row = json.loads(row)
                parent_id = row['parent_id'].split('_')[1]
                body = format_data(row['body'])
                created_utc = row['created_utc']
                score = row['score']                    
                comment_id = row['id']                    
                subreddit = row['subreddit']
                parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)

                existing_comment_score = find_existing_score(parent_id)
                if existing_comment_score:
                    if score > existing_comment_score:
                        if acceptable(body):
                            sql_insert_replace_comment(comment_id,parent_id,parent_data,body,subreddit,created_utc,score)

                else:
                    if acceptable(body):
                        if parent_data:
                            if score >= 2:
                                sql_insert_has_parent(comment_id,parent_id,parent_data,body,subreddit,created_utc,score)
                                paired_rows += 1
                        else:
                            sql_insert_no_parent(comment_id,parent_id,body,subreddit,created_utc,score)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

        if row_counter % 100000 == 0:
            print('Total Rows Read: {}, Paired Rows: {}, Time: {}'.format(row_counter, paired_rows, str(datetime.now())))
```

### Data sample

```
{"subreddit":"SeattleWA","body":"They may just pull out of the Seattle market completely, at least until they have autonomous vehicles.","stickied":false,"gilded":0,"score":1,"author":"music4mic","link_id":"t3_5l79wh","retrieved_on":1485679711,"subreddit_id":"t5_2vbli","controversiality":0,"author_flair_css_class":null,"author_flair_text":null,"created_utc":1483228800,"distinguished":null,"parent_id":"t1_dbts1i6","id":"dbumnq7","edited":false}
```

Comment: A sample of the source?

Comment: Perform the necessary queries directly in SQL, or use Pandas. Using the proper queries, you can bypass some loops entirely.

Comment: You'll want to profile some more. Perhaps it's just the for-loop plus the json.loads(), for example, that's slowing everything down.

Comment: In general, loops are relatively slow in python. You should try avoiding using loops if you can by using other packages such as pandans or even numpy as they are implemented to be more efficient than native python

Comment: @SebastienD - Added to the question

Comment: @9769953 - I'll have a more in depth look to try and figure out what part exactly is cauing the slowdown